# C# MVC - RazorEngine Email Template Create Button with URL link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

**Current working Code:**

```
<html>
<p>http://localhost:57110/MyApps/event?eventId=@Model.EventModel.EventId</p>
</html>
```

**Current Behavior:**

In the email generated, user will click on this URL and open it in browser.

**Question:**

How can I embed this URL in a **button** within the email generated? On the button, I will display text "Click to open this event". Upon click, the behavior should be same as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add an url to a button you should add an `a` tag to your `button`.

```
<button>
    <a href="http://localhost:57110/MyApps/event?eventId=@Model.EventModel.EventId">Click to open this event</a>
</button>
```

Comment: You can remove the `button` tag. A `a` is clickable without button.

Comment: Thanks. `a` is clickable hyperlink text, but it's not a button...<button> tag did not make a difference. Is there a way to create a real button?

Comment: In your email template add inline styles to your button to style it as wished e.g